# Datatables server side request is always GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have the following datatables configuration,

```
var userTable = $('.dataTables-user').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            orderCellsTop: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            serverSide : true,
            processing : true,
            ajax: {
                "url": "/wifi/users/get",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            columns: [
                {"data": "username", "width": "15%"},
                {"data": "acl", "width": "7%"},
                {"data": "groupname", "width": "10%"},
                {"data": "visits", "width": "5%"},
                {"data": "acctstarttime", "width": "10%"},
                {"data": "acctstoptime", "width": "10%"},
                {"data": "acctlastupdatedtime", "width": "10%"}
            ],
            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
                "sSwfPath": "js/plugins/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
        });
```

According to the configuration, server side request should be a POST. This generates a POST in the initial table loading. However all the subsequent calls happens during (sorting, searching, paging) are GET requests and the destination url is not the one specified in ajax, but the window.location.href.

I'm using jquery datatables version 1.10.7. And I have the following list of js libraries imported.

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
```

Is this the expected behavior?

I tried changing the back-end to GET and datatables configurations accordingly, in that case the parameter content are in json object format and it's not sending the request to the specified URL in the ajax configuration. See the attached image captured from firebug console.

[image]

Appreciate your help to sort this out.

**EDIT : Update**

Seems like this is happening because of the column filter plugin. I have the following js code immediately after the previous datatables initialization, once I remove this part issue doesn't come. Is it possible to get both the columnfilter plugin and the datatables server side working together?

```
$('.dataTables-user').dataTable().columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [
                    {"bSortable": false},
                    {type: "select", values: ['Whitelisted', 'Blacklisted', 'normal_user']},
                    {type: "select", values: locationGroups},
                    {"bSortable": false},
                    {"bSortable": false},
                    {"bSortable": false},
                    null,
                    null
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because, column filter plugin has overridden the server side processing functionality and it's not compatible with the newer version of datatables (1.10+). I've removed the overridden server side processing from the plugin and posted the modified version in [this github repo](https://github.com/apremalal/datatables-columnfilter).

Answer (score 0):

There is comma missing after `processing : true`, most likely that is the reason.